# How to write a toString() method that should return complex number in the form a+bi as a string?

Tags: java, string, tostring, complex-numbers

The method should return the string representation for a complex number. The toString() method should return Complex numbers in the form a+bi as a String,where a is the real part and b is the imaginary part

```
public class Complex {
      private double real;
      private double imaginary;

      //1.Complex () : This is the default constructor. 
      public void Complex(){
          this.real = 0;
          this.imaginary = 0;
      }

      //2.Complex(double,double) 
       public void Complex(double r, double i){
           this.real = r;
           this.imaginary = i;
       }

       //3.double getReal()
       public double getReal(){
           return this.real;
       }

       //4.void setReal(double)
      public void setReal(double real){
          this.real = real;
      }

      //5.double getImginary()
      public double getImaginary(){
          return this.imaginary ;
      }

      //6. void setImaginary(double)
      public void setImaginary(double imaginary){
          this.imaginary = imaginary;
      }

      //7.String toString()
      public String toString1() {
            return this.real + " + " + this.imaginary + "i";
      }

      //8.Complex add(Complex)
      public Complex add(Complex n){
          double r=this.real+n.real;
          double i=this.imaginary + n.imaginary;
          Complex s= new Complex(r,i);
          return s;

      }

      //9.Complex sub(Complex)
      public Complex sub(Complex n){
          double r= this.real- n.real;
          double i= this.imaginary - n.imaginary;
          Complex s= new Complex(r,i);
          return s;
      }

      //10.Complex mul(Complex)
      public Complex mul(Complex n){
          double r= this.real*n.real - this.imaginary*n.imaginary;
          double i= this.real*n.imaginary+this.imaginary*n.real;
          Complex s=new Complex(r,i);
          return s;
      }


      //11.Complex div(Complex)
      public Complex div(Complex n){
          double r= this.real/n.real- this.imaginary/n.imaginary;
          double i = this.real/n.imaginary+this.imaginary/n.real;
          Complex s=new Complex(r,i);
          return s;
```

}
}

Comment: how does the class looks like???

Comment: Show us the basic class structure you are using like what are the fields, how are you getting input `a` and `b`.

Comment: How would you build that as a string, outside a `toString()` method? Well, do the same, just inside a `toString()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `toString()` to get the desired description of the instances/classes.

Code:

```
class ComplexNum
{
    int a,b;

    ComplexNum(int a , int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return a + "+" + b + "i";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ComplexNum c = new ComplexNum(10,12);
        System.out.println("Complex Number is: " + c);
    }
}
```

I hope it helped.